# how to send a "Ctrl+Break" to a subprocess via pid or handler

Tags: python, controls, sendkeys

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['c:\windows\system32\ping.exe','127.0.0.1', '-t'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
while True: 
  line = proc.stdout.readline() 
  print "ping result:", line.rstrip() 
  #sendkey("Ctrl+Break", proc)            # i need this here, this is not for terminate the process but to print a statistics result for the ping result.
```

If someone know how to do it, please share with me, thanks!

Comment: Send the process a signal, not the keys.

Comment: creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP should be added when invoke subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows? Try this:

```
import signal
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGBREAK)
```

If you meant a signal interrupt (`kill -2`)

```
import signal
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Great, I didn't notice the send_signal on Popen object ;)

Comment: thanks, i also found os.kill(proc.pid, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)  works as well in windows

Answer (score 2):

The Ctrl+Break keys is a SIGBREAK signal.

Under linux, you can send this signal with `kill` command, on Windows, this is slightly different. You can use the [SendSignal](http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendSignal/) tool.