# Pause a FFmpeg encoding in a Python Popen subprocess on Windows

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, signals, popen

I am trying to pause an encode of FFmpeg while it is in a **non-shell** subprocess (This is important to how it plays into a larger program). This can be done by presssing the "Pause / Break" key on the keyboard by itself, and I am trying to send that to Popen.

The command itself must be cross platform compatible, so I cannot wrap it in any way, but I can send signals or run functions that are platform specific as needed.

I looked at [how to send a "Ctrl+Break" to a subprocess via pid or handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186543/how-to-send-a-ctrlbreak-to-a-subprocess-via-pid-or-handler) and it suggested to send a signal, but that raised a "ValueError: Unsupported signal: 21"

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import signal


if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = "ffmpeg.exe -y -i example_video.mkv -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -preset slow -crf 18 output.mkv"
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, shell=False)

    try:
        proc.send_signal(signal.SIGBREAK)
    finally:
        proc.wait()
```

Then attempted to use GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent to create a Ctrl+Break event as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import ctypes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = "ffmpeg.exe -y -i example_video.mkv -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -preset slow -crf 18 output.mkv"
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, shell=False)

    try:
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(1, proc.pid)
    finally:
        proc.wait()
```

I have tried `psutil` pause feature, but it keeps the CPU load really high even when "paused".

Even though it wouldn't work with the program overall, I have at least tried setting `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` which makes the SIGBREAK not error, but also not pause it. For the Ctrl-Break event will entirely stop the encode instead of pausing it.

Comment: Any solution yet?  I have been trying to figure this out.

Comment: I think sending `c` to stdin causes the command menu to be shown and the effect is the same. Maybe `proc.stdin.write(b'c');proc.stdin.flush()` Then just send an enter to stdin resume? I _think_ that may work?

Comment: @sytech Pressing `c` does pause it to wait for filter input, and works cross platform, but has the same issue of causing one CPU to stay spiked. Whereas using the `pause` button in powershell or `kill -STOP` on linux makes them all free up. However that may be best possible answer and I'm just looking for the impossible.

Comment: @CasualDemon In my machine, `psutil` is working fine, and the CPU is not utilized when the process is paused. In Windows, [PsSuspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) is also working. The way I tested is adding `sleep(60)` between suspend and resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux/Unix solution:

```py
import subprocess, os, signal
# ...
# Start the task:
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., start_new_session=True)
# ...
def send_signal_to_task(pid, signal):
        #gpid = os.getpgid(pid)  # WARNING This does not work
        gpid = pid  # But this does!
        print(f"Sending {signal} to process group {gpid}...")
        os.killpg(gpid, signal)
# ...
# Pause and resume:
send_signal_to_task(proc.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
send_signal_to_task(proc.pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

Notice `start_new_session=True` in `Popen` call and using of `os.killpg` instead of `os.kill` in `send_signal_to_task` function. The reason for this is the same as as reason for why you have large CPU usage even in paused state as you reported. `ffmpeg` spawns a number of child processes. `start_new_session=True` will create a new process group and `os.killpg` sends signal to all processes in group.

Cross-platform solution is supposed to be provided by `psutil` module but you probably should research whether it supports process groups as the variant above:

```py
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.pids()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 46, 48, 50, 51, 178, 182, 222, 223, 224, 268, 1215,
 1216, 1220, 1221, 1243, 1244, 1301, 1601, 2237, 2355, 2637, 2774, 3932,
 4176, 4177, 4185, 4187, 4189, 4225, 4243, 4245, 4263, 4282, 4306, 4311,
 4312, 4313, 4314, 4337, 4339, 4357, 4358, 4363, 4383, 4395, 4408, 4433,
 4443, 4445, 4446, 5167, 5234, 5235, 5252, 5318, 5424, 5644, 6987, 7054,
 7055, 7071]
>>> p = psutil.Process(7055)
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.resume()
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/psutil/

Some pointers on emulating process groups in Windows: [Popen waiting for child process even when the immediate child has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243807/popen-waiting-for-child-process-even-when-the-immediate-child-has-terminated/13256908#13256908)